# XAMPP view php error log in real time

Tags: xampp, error-log

I have done a lot research on this and I can not seem to find an answer. I am wondering if you can view the PHP error log on XAMPP in real time just like if I were using a web server using the tail -f command. I know the command would not be the same but I was wondering if it is possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from IDE, or you can use Xdebug helper addon, for browser. For example laravel framework has inbuilt debugger in debug mode you get split screen with all debug info at the bottom live from framework itself. P.S. You can still use tail -f, just install http://www.mingw.org/ its shell for windows. Or Get-Content [pathtologfile] in PowerShell:

Parameter Set: Path
Get-Content [-Path]  [-Credential  ] [-Delimiter  ] [-Encoding  {Unknown | String | Unicode | Byte | BigEndianUnicode | UTF8 | UTF7 | UTF32 | Ascii | Default | Oem | BigEndianUTF32} ] [-Exclude  ] [-Filter  ] [-Force] [-Include  ] [-InformationAction  {SilentlyContinue | Stop | Continue | Inquire | Ignore | Suspend} ] [-InformationVariable  ] [-Raw] [-ReadCount  ] [-Stream  ] [-Tail  ] [-TotalCount  ] [-Wait] [-UseTransaction] [ ]

Parameter Set: LiteralPath
Get-Content -LiteralPath  [-Credential  ] [-Delimiter  ] [-Encoding  {Unknown | String | Unicode | Byte | BigEndianUnicode | UTF8 | UTF7 | UTF32 | Ascii | Default | Oem | BigEndianUTF32} ] [-Exclude  ] [-Filter  ] [-Force] [-Include  ] [-InformationAction  {SilentlyContinue | Stop | Continue | Inquire | Ignore | Suspend} ] [-InformationVariable  ] [-Raw] [-ReadCount  ] [-Stream  ] [-Tail  ] [-TotalCount  ] [-Wait] [-UseTransaction] [ ]